# Why the inputs are not working right with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Could someone explain to me why I can't get the current selected radio-button in this simple example. I'm trying to generate dynamically the radio-buttons with an ng-repeat directive and get the current radio-button selected using ng-model.
Like this:

Template:

```
<div ng-repeat="kind in movieKinds">
    <input type="radio" name="movies" ng-value="kind" ng-model="kindSelected"> {{kind.name}}<br>
</div>
Selected Movie :{{kindSelected}}
```

Controller:

```
mymodule.controller('MainCtrl', [ '$scope',function ($scope) {

    $scope.movieKinds = [
        {'name' : 'Action', 'movies' : ['Action#1', 'Action#2', 'Action#3']},
        {'name' : 'Comedy', 'movies' : ['Comedy#1', 'Comedy#2', 'Comedy#3']},
        {'name' : 'Drama', 'movies' : ['Drama#1', 'Drama#2']},
        {'name' : 'Horror', 'movies' : ['Horror#1']}
    ];

}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `ng-repeat` does create a new child scope(prototypically inherited) on each iteration when it repeats a template on wherever `ng-repeat` directive has been placed.

> **So what happens when `ng-repeat` creates a new prototypically inherited child scope?**
>
> In the child scope it carries all properties in which `primitive`
>   property initial value taken while creating child scope & object
>   values are taken with their references so update in parent scope value
>   will update in child scope value & vice versa.

Here in your case you had `ng-model="kindSelected"` variable inside `ng-repeat` so that scope variable got create inside the `ng-repeat` scope and doesn't available outside `ng-repeat` directive.

To fix such a problem you could use `object` while defining `ng-model` so that you could follow `Dot rule` while defining `ng-model`. That means you could define a object called as `$scope.model` inside controller & then add `kindSelected` property so that the value will get updated on selection of checkbox.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="kind in movieKinds">
    <input type="radio" name="movies" ng-value="kind" ng-model="kindSelected"> {{kind.name}}<br>
</div>
Selected Movie :{{model.kindSelected}}
```

**Code**

```
$scope.model = {};
```

---

The other way to fix this problem is to use `controllerAs` syntax which will use alias of controller so the scope hierarchy related problem doesn't happen on HTML. Whichever controller variable you want you could use that alias of the controller.

Comment: Good explanation :)

Comment: @developer033 Thank you mate :-)

Comment: @PankajParkar : when using the Dot rule while defining ng-model, like in your example i have to referer the model created in the controller, to can work properly, right? like: ng-model="model.kindSelected" and after that, i can used like: {{model.kindSelected}} outside the chield scope

Comment: correct, are you facing any problem with it? I had shown in the example, how code should look like..

Comment: thank you very much, a great explanation!

Comment: Pleased to hear that, Thanks :)