# AngularJS problems with radio button not selecting

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I'm trying to catch the ng-change event on a radio button, but the problem is that it only gets checked when I click for second time on any of the radios in the same group. Also, when I click on a radio for first time, ng-changed gets called, but it doesn't if I click again in another radio button or in the same one.

```
<div>
<div ng-repeat="element in questions" ng-class="{'in':$first,'hidden': !$first}">
    <h1>{{element.question}}</h1>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" ng-value="A" ng-model="$parent.answer" ng-change="enableSubmit()">{{element.answerA}}</input>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" ng-value="B" ng-model="$parent.answer" ng-change="enableSubmit()">{{element.answerB}}</input>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" ng-value="C" ng-model="$parent.answer" ng-change="enableSubmit()">{{element.answerC}}</input>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="prev" class="hidden" ng-click="prevQuestion()">Anterior</button>
<button id="next" ng-click="nextQuestion()" disabled>Siguiente</button>
</div>
```

What could be wrong with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, `input` tag is a *self-closing* tag, then your HTML is semantically incorrect.

Comment: Done that, but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: You could provide a simple demo in plnkr to demonstrate how is your JS controller and complete view.. it's hard to tell something this way..

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/v00rhhC48IL3PlnSIlRp?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ng-repeat` creates its own `$scope`, as you can see in this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275526/why-the-inputs-are-not-working-right-with-ng-repeat#answer-38275584), you must use, preferably, [***controller-as-syntax***](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) to achieve what you want.

A demo working with your code:

<kbd>[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/XFkgE9qAZ00RHXc7F79k?p=preview)</kbd>

**Note:** I don't know if you're using `jQuery` for something else besides *hide*/*disable* buttons, but **all** that things can be easily done with **Angular**, like this:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="main.answer" value="A" ng-change="enableSubmit()" />

$scope.enableSubmit = function() {
    $('#next').prop('disabled', false);
};
```

Should be just this in **view**:

```
<button ng-disabled="!main.answer" id="next" ng-click="nextQuestion()">Siguiente</button>
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: You're welcome, can you check the answer as correct? Just clicking on the left <=====