# Missing function and error when binding object to radio button group

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to bind an object to a radio button group. Please refer the two snippets of code in this post. The first uses ng-repeat to loop but it fails. I manually repeat the element in the second example but it works. Why does ng-repeat cause this issue?

**Example 1**

```js
  angular
      .module('listParser', [])
      .factory('Item', function() {
        return function(id, name) {
          this.id = id;
          this.name = name;
        }
      })
      .controller('default', ['$scope', 'Item', function($scope, Item) {
        var collection = [];
        collection.push(new Item(0, 'Alpha'));
        collection.push(new Item(1, 'Beta'));
        
        $scope.collection = collection;
        $scope.lucky = collection[0];
      }]);
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-app="listParser" ng-controller="default">
   <div class="radio-group">
    <ul><li ng-repeat="item in collection"><input type="radio" name="group" ng-value="item" ng-model="lucky"/></li></ul>
   </div>
   <div class="description">
    {{lucky.name}}
   </div>
  </div>
```

**Example 2**

```js
  angular
        .module('listParser', [])
        .factory('Item', function() {
          return function(id, name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
          }
        })
        .controller('default', ['$scope', 'Item', function($scope, Item) {
          var collection = [];
          collection.push(new Item(0, 'Alpha'));
          collection.push(new Item(1, 'Beta'));
          
          $scope.collection = collection;
          $scope.lucky = collection[0];
        }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="listParser" ng-controller="default">
      <div class="radio-group">
      <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" name="group" ng-value="collection[0]" ng-model="lucky"/></li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="group" ng-value="collection[1]" ng-model="lucky"/></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
      {{lucky.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you open the console ? Maybe you can check what is the error on example one. Would you mind sharing the error if there exists one?

Comment: Use of `$parent` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), a symptom of a deeper problem. If there is more than one level of inherited scope between the `ng-model` directive and the Model variable, using `$parent` will fail.

Comment: @georgeawg, thank you. Editing the question likewise (:

Comment: This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of always have a '.' in your ng-models http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m  – watch 3 minutes worth. Misko demonstrates the primitive binding issue with `ng-switch`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work with `ng-repeat`, because `ng-repeat` does create a prototypically inherited child scope. What that means is, it creates a `lucky` property inside the `scope` on `ng-repeat` element, that `lucky` scope variable isn't available outside `ng-repeat` element. You could forcefully use `$parent` prefix before `lucky` variable, that will eventually help you to point `lucky` to parent scope. But don't do that in production code, it is considered as bad practice.

In other case it wasn't issue, because all scope were on same `context`, where in case of `ng-repeat` it wasn't.

To solve this issue from the root, you can use either `Dot rule` or `controllerAs` pattern while defining `ng-model`

Here is [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38275584/2435473) explains the same thing about `ng-repeat`

Comment: I think this answers my question but could you please link an article for `dot rule` and `controllerAs` pattern? It wasn't trivial to find. I could probably look deeper and find it but it will definitely complete the answer (:

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m  – watch 3 minutes worth. Misko demonstrates the primitive binding issue with `ng-switch`.